# How to add constrains inside custom UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I want to add constrainst to UILabel
My custom UIView class:

```
class LabelView: UIView {

    public var label: UILabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = frame
        prepareUI()
    }  
    func prepareUI() {     
        self.label.text = "SOME TEXT"
        self.label.sizeToFit()
        self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.label.textAlignment = .center
        self.addSubview(self.label)
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        self.label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
    }
}
```

after running I get the following error and the UILabel is placed in the top left corner of the UIView:

2021-02-13 02:32:26.698694+1000 SwiftHello[96793:1625524] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000606c10 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x142616930.minX == 0   (active, names: '|':SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000606c60 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x142616930.width == 93.5   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006061c0 UILabel:0x142616930.centerX == SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.centerX   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606300 UILabel:0x142616930.width == 0.5*SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.width   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006061c0 UILabel:0x142616930.centerX == SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.centerX   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-13 02:32:26.698920+1000 SwiftHello[96793:1625524] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000606cb0 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x142616930.minY == 0   (active, names: '|':SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000606d00 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x142616930.height == 20.5   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006062b0 UILabel:0x142616930.centerY == SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.centerY   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606350 UILabel:0x142616930.height == 0.2*SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.height   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006062b0 UILabel:0x142616930.centerY == SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.centerY   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-13 02:32:26.702639+1000 SwiftHello[96793:1625524] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000606c60 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x142616930.width == 93.5   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606300 UILabel:0x142616930.width == 0.5*SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.width   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606940 SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.width == 0.85*UIView:0x14260e930.width   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606da0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIView:0x14260e930.width == 375   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606300 UILabel:0x142616930.width == 0.5*SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.width   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-02-13 02:32:26.702816+1000 SwiftHello[96793:1625524] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600000606d00 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x142616930.height == 20.5   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606350 UILabel:0x142616930.height == 0.2*SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.height   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606990 SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.height == 0.1*UIView:0x14260e930.height   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606d50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x14260e930.height == 667   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000606350 UILabel:0x142616930.height == 0.2*SwiftHello.LabelView:0x1426167c0.height   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing this line:

```
self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

You've set it on **self** but not on the **label**.

Comment: Oops, it's time to get some sleep. Thanks :)